# Azure CloudBlobClient.ListContainers() returns 400 for DevelopmentStorage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-storage-emulator

Am just running some experiments with CloudBlobStorage using the Development Storage Account, and while VS2013 Server Explorer can enumerate Blob containers just fine, my code returns a 400 error.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I've searched high and low.

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
client.ListContainers().ToList();  // throws StorageException with 400 error
```

Note: If I call `GetContainerReference()` against a container known to exist it returns correctly.

Comment: Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284787/azure-400-bad-request-on-every-request/20284900#20284900. More than likely it is caused by storage client library version 3.0.0.0.

Comment: @GauravMantri That's done it. I just used the NuGet UI to pull the WindowsAzure.Storage package.

Comment: I'd suggest marking this question as a duplicate of the other one referenced, so it can be properly closed.