# Cannot create table on Azure development storage

Tags: c#, azure, .net-4.5, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I cannot create a table, named "people" on my local machine. I have started the Azure emulator by starting the "Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v2.2". I have pulled the latest Azure client library from NuGet, which is version 3.0.3.0. The .NET version is 4.5 and my VS is 2012 Ultimate. I run this code from Windows 8.1, on a x64 system.

This is my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace AzureTablesTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");
            table.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
    }
}
```

I have made sure that the emulator is running by checking the emualtor GUI:

[image: Azure Emulator GUI]

When I run the test code from VS it throws this exception:

[image: Azure Storage Exception with code line reference]

The strange thing is that when I open Azure Storage Explorer, create a development account, I can create tables and entities. When I reset the tables from the Emulator GUI I can see that the storage Explorer is emptied as well (after a refresh). I have tried to create a table through the Explorer and see if I got any errors when creating the table with my simple console program above, and I get the same error. So I cannot read or write with the console program, but I can with the Explorer.

Does someone know why I cannot create tables through my simple console program, but why I can through Azure Storage Explorer? I have even tried to run the console program listed above outside VS as an administrator, which gave me the exact same error as shown above.

**UPDATE**
Installing Storage Emulator 2.2.1 Preview, as this link describes [Azure 400 Bad Request on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284787/azure-400-bad-request-on-every-request/20284900#20284900), resolved my issue.

Comment: This is a known issue with storage emulator 2.2. Please see this thread for more information and resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284787/azure-400-bad-request-on-every-request/20284900#20284900.

Comment: Oh I have acctually read about that, but I thought that it was fixed. I will try this. Thanks allot!!

Comment: @GauravMantri, if you want you can answer my question. Or else I am going to answer it myself. So I can close it.

Comment: That's OK. You can answer the question. I have marked it to be closed (with reason as `Duplicate`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Storage Emulator 2.2.1 Preview, as this link describes [Azure 400 Bad Request on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284787/azure-400-bad-request-on-every-request/20284900#20284900), resolved my issue.