# Azure Blob Storage Emulator Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-emulator

I am trying to write a test app that will allow me to access Azure Blob Storage. I am using VS2013 and have Azure SDK V2.2 installed.  The Azure Storage Emulator is running. However, the location used by the storage emulator

C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\dftmp\wadd

seems to be different to the location used in VS2013 IDE. I'm not sure where that location is. I can create a container and upload files using the VS2013 IDE, but I then don't see them in the Storage Emulator location, so I have assumed they are different.

More simportantly, the code below fails with a **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.** error when it executes the line:

```
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Any ideas what is going on and why I can't get this to work in VS2013 using the emulator? It works just fine if I substitute my actual Azure credentials and write the file to the Azure Storage. I really want to build this test solution and do some debugging before moving a solution completely onto Azure.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Storage Emulator credentials
    string connectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
    string myContainer = "images";

    CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount;
    CloudBlobClient blobClient;
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;
    BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions;
    StorageCredentials storageCredentials;

    private void InitialiseBlobStorage()
    {
        cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(myContainer);
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitialiseBlobStorage();

        // Add code to upload image here
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the Azure .NET library versions you are using are compatible with the version 2.2 of the emulator. IIRC, version 3.1 of Windows Azure Storage library on Nuget is not compatible with 2.2 and you'll get a 400 response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284787/azure-400-bad-request-on-every-request was the fix. Many thanks.