# Azure Blob Sdk - REST or SDK? Emulator?

Tags: azure

I am looking at using blob storage to store some backups and I want to do it programmatically.

First question is there really any advantage over the SDK vs REST API?

Second question how can I simulate the blog storage on local host? I found [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/#setup-connection-string) but I was planning to use an asp.net mvc 5 site instead. It says there is some emulator but only talks about if you use a cloud project.

Edit

I can't install the emulator

```
=== Logging started: 4/25/2014  10:34:55 ===
Action start 10:34:55: INSTALL.
Action start 10:34:55: AppSearch.
Action ended 10:34:55: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 10:34:55: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 10:34:55: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 10:34:55: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: CostInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: FileCost.
Action ended 10:34:55: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: SetREINSTALLMODE.
Action ended 10:34:55: SetREINSTALLMODE. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: CostFinalize.
Action ended 10:34:55: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: SetCommandForRunInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: SetCommandForRunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallValidate.
Action ended 10:34:55: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 10:34:55: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 10:34:55: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveRegistryValues.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveShortcuts.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallFiles.
Action ended 10:34:55: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RunInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: RunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: CreateShortcuts.
Action ended 10:34:55: CreateShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: WriteRegistryValues.
Action ended 10:34:55: WriteRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RegisterUser.
Action ended 10:34:55: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 10:34:55: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 10:34:55: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: PublishProduct.
Action ended 10:34:55: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallFinalize.
CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.0.0.0 command line tool
CAQuietExec:  Error: No available SQL Instance was found.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff6: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff6: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 10:38:33: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action ended 10:38:34: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {CF5CD495-AEDE-42DA-B7CF-A70D398D4E6A}
Property(S): RunInitialize = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect
Property(S): DOTNET4FULL = 4.5.51641
Property(S): LOCALDBINSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): SQLEXPRESSVERSION = 10.0.2531.0
Property(S): TARGETDIR = G:\
Property(S): StorageEmulatorMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): STORAGEEMUDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(S): REINSTALLMODE = amus
Property(S): WindowsAzureMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Azure\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): WINDOWSAZUREDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\
Property(S): MICROSOFTSDKSDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.0\1356EC2B8E2DBE40C737E5555DD11DFA1BE1AB47\
Property(S): MSIRMSHUTDOWN = 1
Property(S): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIR
Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(S): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(S): Manufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
Property(S): ProductCode = {6DFDA7BE-32F0-4E6F-B304-3567E656D18C}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.0
Property(S): ProductVersion = 3.0.6848.39
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERVERSIONDETECTED;OLDEMULATORPACKAGEDETECTED;OLDERVERSIONDETECTED
Property(S): WixPdbPath = o:\bttemp\149736\obj.amd64fre\services\xstore\rdpackages\storageemulatorpackage\objfre\amd64\en-us\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.wixpdb
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\win8.hub\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {C5E0C90F-EFDF-4030-8F5D-2A3AF97D8B80}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): REBOOT = ReallySuppress
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 5180
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\win8.hub\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\win8\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\win8\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\win8\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 8142
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 5083
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = win8
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-1097169495-1557939910-592522955-27415
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = win8
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 10:38:34
Property(S): Date = 4/25/2014
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.16384
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = win8
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\fab232b.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.0\1356EC2B8E2DBE40C737E5555DD11DFA1BE1AB47\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = G:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.0\1356EC2B8E2DBE40C737E5555DD11DFA1BE1AB47\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {6DFDA7BE-32F0-4E6F-B304-3567E656D18C}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (34:88) [10:38:34:039]: Product: Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.0 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (34:88) [10:38:34:039]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.0. Product Version: 3.0.6848.39. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

=== Logging stopped: 4/25/2014  10:38:34 ===
```

Answer (score 0):

> First question is there really any advantage over the SDK vs REST API?

The advantage to me with SDK over REST API is that you don't have to write code to consume REST API. SDK (rather Storage Client Library which is part of SDK) does that for you so your time-to-market reduces considerably. In the earlier days of Azure changes to REST API came sooner and then after some time implementation of these REST API in SDK come. However recently they both are more or less in sync.

One thing I would like to say is that while REST API and Storage Client library are maintained by one team (Azure Storage team) but the SDK (which also contains local storage emulator) is maintained by another team and their release cycles don't often match. A good example is the release of Storage Client Library v3.x which had support for CORS. When this version of library was released, SDK was still at version 2.x and only supported Storage Client Library v2.x and that caused a lot of grief (e.g [Azure 400 Bad Request on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284787/azure-400-bad-request-on-every-request)). So you may want to take that into consideration.

Secondly I am assuming that you would use .Net for application development. If that's not the case then you may be better off consuming the REST API as Storage Client libraries in other languages are still not at par with the latest version of REST API.

> Second question how can I simulate the blob storage on local host?

When you install Azure SDK, a local storage emulator gets installed in that process. You can use local storage emulator to test blob storage locally. There's no need to have a cloud service project to use local storage emulator. You can use it in any kind of application. Only catch is that you would have to manually start the local storage emulator (which gets started automatically if you debug a cloud service project). Again if you're using .Net storage client library, here're the two ways you could connect to this local storage emulator through code:

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
```

or

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I am going with the sdk as that was my thought that don't need to write the code to connect to the api. So I just put that line in my C# code(ie global.asax) but where does it get saved to on my local drive? How do I start the local storage emulator up is it a program?

Comment: `How do I start the local storage emulator up is it a program?` - Assuming you're using SDK Version 2.3, you may find this post useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2014/04/04/managing-storage-emulator-in-azure-sdk-version-2-3/. The command to start the emulator would be `WAStorageEmulator start`. Not sure what you meant by `So I just put that line in my C# code(ie global.asax) but where does it get saved to on my local drive?`. Could you please explain?

Comment: I thought that was line was like a flag to say that all your code is in emulator mode, it seems like I will need an if statement to do one of the 2 lines above and then something like this CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
  CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")); I am guessing though instead of CloudConfigurationManage I would use the connection string manager from the web.config?

Comment: Aah I see. So you could use CloudConfigurationManager and it will read the connection string from web.config's `<appSettings>` section (no need to define this connection string under `<connectionString>` section.

Comment: really so waht I just make a regular asppsetting key and value and use the CloudConfigurationManager and it will get it from the appSettings? Any advantage over the ConfigurationManager?I am still not sure where the emulator saves the files but first I am having trouble installing the emulator through web platform as it keeps failing

Comment: I posted the error log, seems like something to do with sql?

Comment: Yes. Here's the link for more information on CloudConfigurationManager: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.getsetting.aspx. Emulator actually uses a SQL Server DB to store all files and data (except VHD files which it stores in AppData folders).

Comment: I have SQL 2012 server installed so not sure why it fails.

Comment: I too have SQL Server 2012 installed. Do you have localDB installed as well?

Comment: What do you mean loacldb installed as well? I need to manually create a datbabase for the emulator? Can't the webapi installer do that for me if it needs it?

Comment: When you initialize emulator, by default it creates a database in localDB. Not sure why the installer is failing on you. May be post this as a separate question?

Comment: Agreed, I made a separate post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307477/azure-storage-emulator-wont-install