# Azure Storage Emulator Won't Install

Tags: azure

I can't install the azure storage emulator through web platform installer.

```
=== Logging started: 4/25/2014  10:34:55 ===
Action start 10:34:55: INSTALL.
Action start 10:34:55: AppSearch.
Action ended 10:34:55: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 10:34:55: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 10:34:55: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 10:34:55: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: CostInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: FileCost.
Action ended 10:34:55: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: SetREINSTALLMODE.
Action ended 10:34:55: SetREINSTALLMODE. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: CostFinalize.
Action ended 10:34:55: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: SetCommandForRunInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: SetCommandForRunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallValidate.
Action ended 10:34:55: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 10:34:55: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 10:34:55: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveRegistryValues.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveShortcuts.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 10:34:55: RemoveFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallFiles.
Action ended 10:34:55: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RunInitialize.
Action ended 10:34:55: RunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: CreateShortcuts.
Action ended 10:34:55: CreateShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: WriteRegistryValues.
Action ended 10:34:55: WriteRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RegisterUser.
Action ended 10:34:55: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 10:34:55: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 10:34:55: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: PublishProduct.
Action ended 10:34:55: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 10:34:55: InstallFinalize.
CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.0.0.0 command line tool
CAQuietExec:  Error: No available SQL Instance was found.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff6: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff6: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 10:38:33: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action ended 10:38:34: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {CF5CD495-AEDE-42DA-B7CF-A70D398D4E6A}
Property(S): RunInitialize = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect
Property(S): DOTNET4FULL = 4.5.51641
Property(S): LOCALDBINSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): SQLEXPRESSVERSION = 10.0.2531.0
Property(S): TARGETDIR = G:\
Property(S): StorageEmulatorMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): STORAGEEMUDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(S): REINSTALLMODE = amus
Property(S): WindowsAzureMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Azure\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): WINDOWSAZUREDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\
Property(S): MICROSOFTSDKSDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.0\1356EC2B8E2DBE40C737E5555DD11DFA1BE1AB47\
Property(S): MSIRMSHUTDOWN = 1
Property(S): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIR
Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(S): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(S): Manufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
Property(S): ProductCode = {6DFDA7BE-32F0-4E6F-B304-3567E656D18C}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.0
Property(S): ProductVersion = 3.0.6848.39
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERVERSIONDETECTED;OLDEMULATORPACKAGEDETECTED;OLDERVERSIONDETECTED
Property(S): WixPdbPath = o:\bttemp\149736\obj.amd64fre\services\xstore\rdpackages\storageemulatorpackage\objfre\amd64\en-us\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.wixpdb
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\win8.hub\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {C5E0C90F-EFDF-4030-8F5D-2A3AF97D8B80}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): REBOOT = ReallySuppress
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 5180
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\win8.hub\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\win8\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\win8\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\win8\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 8142
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 5083
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = win8
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-1097169495-1557939910-592522955-27415
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = win8
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 10:38:34
Property(S): Date = 4/25/2014
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.16384
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = win8
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\fab232b.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.0\1356EC2B8E2DBE40C737E5555DD11DFA1BE1AB47\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = G:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\Users\win8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.0\1356EC2B8E2DBE40C737E5555DD11DFA1BE1AB47\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {6DFDA7BE-32F0-4E6F-B304-3567E656D18C}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (34:88) [10:38:34:039]: Product: Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.0 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (34:88) [10:38:34:039]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.0. Product Version: 3.0.6848.39. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

=== Logging stopped: 4/25/2014  10:38:34 ===
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23007597/130015) but did not understand what he meant by

I just deleted them manually. Recreated the v11.0:

> ```
> sqllocaldb stop v11.0
> sqllocaldb delete v11.0
> sqllocaldb create v11.0
> ```
>
> And reinstalled...

I saw these 2 files

> ```
> WAStorageEmulatorDb30.mdf
> WAStorageEmulatorDb30_log.ldf
> ```

but it still fails to install.

Edit 2

This is the errors I see

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        SQLLocalDB 11.0
Date:          5/5/2014 9:44:32 AM
Event ID:      267
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      chobo2
Description:
LocalDB instance is corrupted. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="SQLLocalDB 11.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="35269">267</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-05-05T16:44:32.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>74923</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>chobo2</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>


Log Name:      Application
Source:        SQLLocalDB 11.0
Date:          5/5/2014 9:44:32 AM
Event ID:      261
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      chobo2
Description:
Cannot access LocalDB instance folder: %%LOCALAPPDATA%%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\<instance name>.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="SQLLocalDB 11.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="35269">261</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-05-05T16:44:32.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>74922</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>chobo2</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Can you check if the binaries were installed? They can usually be found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator\

Comment: Don't see Storage Emulator folder.

Answer (score 53):

I encountered similar issues when updating to v2.5. I tried everything outlined in the various blogs and technet forums with no luck but it seems like the advice given was correct, just slightly different for my case.

- **Uninstall all previous version of azure sdks**

  - ***Optional*** and probably not related to fixing my issue.  I uninstalled all azure sdks, authoring tools, azure tools for VS, azure libraries for .Net, storage emulators and compute emulators.
- **Delete WAStorageEmulatorDb files**

  - Next up was to clean up any previous WAStorageEmulator database files. For most users these appear to be kept in `c:\users\{user}\WAStorageEmulatorDb*.*`.

    - `sqllocaldb stop v11.0`
    - `sqllocaldb delete v11.0`
    - manually delete c:\users\{user}\WAStorageEmulatorDb*.*
    - `sqllocaldb create v11.0`
- At this point reinstalling Azure SDK 2.5 via Web Platform Installer failed to install with the following error.

  - `CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.0.0.0 command line tool
    CAQuietExec:  Error: Cannot create database.
    CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: Command line returned an error.
    CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: CAQuietExec Failed`
- **This is where I noticed my environment was different**. Running `sqllocaldb info` I noticed I had 4 instances, *V11.0*, two instances which hosted personal databases and a 4th one called *MSSQLLocalDB*. If you open `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` in *Visual Studio - SQL Server Object Explorer* you should should see `WAStorageEmulatorDb`. The problem for me was that my WAStorageEmulatorDb wasn't being stored in v11.0 as it was for other people, so deleting `v11.0` didn't help.
- **Delete WAStorageEmulatorDb files again**. So now that I knew where my WAStorageEmulatorDb was, I re-ran the following

  - `sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB`
  - `sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB`
  - `sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB`
- **Re-install Azure SDK 2.5** via Web Platform Installer completed successfully.
- Lastly, running `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe init` followed by `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe start` started successfully.

  - To verify you should also have new `c:\users\{user}\WAStorageEmulatorDb34.*` files.

Comment: I ran into the same issue updating to v2.6 with Azure Storage Emulator 4.0 and couldn't get it to work. deleting `MSSQLLocalDB` was the key.

Comment: Same here. After deleting MSSQLLocalDB installation went smooth.

Comment: I also had to delete c:\users\{user}\AzureStorageEmulatorDB*.* to get it working.

Comment: This solved my issue as well, with one important difference: MSSQLLocalDB wasn't visible in SQL Server Object Explorer, but did show up when I ran 'sqllocaldb info'. Either way, deleting MSSQLLocalDb and recreating it did the trick for me.

Comment: You don't need to recreate MSSQLLocalDB (it failed for me on the command line anyway), I just ran the installer again and it created me the DB. Also, as Oliver said, you need to delete AzureStorageEmulatorDB from your user directory

Comment: I had this same issue with the upgrade to 2.9. Just doing these three steps cleared the problem:  •sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB
•sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB
•sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: Thanks so much!  It's the second time today sqllocaldb has screwed itself up and wasted my time :(

Answer (score 12):

The solution you quoted should work for you as well, we can clean up those problematic files with a command.

That post is telling you to execute those commands using powershell. Open powershell as an administrator (or type powershell from an admin cmd.exe prompt) and type the following:

```
sqllocaldb stop v11.0
sqllocaldb delete v11.0
del %UserProfile%\WAStorageEmulatorDb30*.*
sqllocaldb create v11.0
```

Comment: `delete` should be `del` and `win8` should be `{username}`. This works flawlessly. The crucial part is removing the WAStorageEmulatorDB30 files.

Comment: @Matt Davies I did not have WaStorageEmulator, I uninstalled everything azure and now I have those files, the emulator seems to have installed as well but when I run it the cmd line windows starts up and executes the command but it seems to hang(just see a blinking dash) and nothing happens.

Comment: @Bart thanks for the tip on del - fixed that. I'd used win8 as the username in the example based on the earlier logs from chobo2.

Comment: @chobo2 Can you please paste the output of
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe" /devstore:start
and anything you can find related in Event Viewer. I'll see if I can spot the problem for you.

Comment: Ok I will post the errors(seems to be a problem with db), I wonder if it has something to do because I have both VS 2012 and Vs 2013 on my computer and that I need to install 2 different versions from web platform for it.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:

- Go to Windows' 'Uninstall/change programs'
- Select Microsoft Visual Studio and hit **change**
- Then select the Web Developer tools and the SQL Server Data Tools and install.

If I then re-run the Azure SDK installation, everything's fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with  installing to a brand new Windows 8.1 installation. Matt Davies's solution did not work as such, since the sqllocaldb instance had never been started, but still got me on the right trail.

Simply opening C:\Users\{myuser} and removing all files named `WAStorageEmulatorDb3*` solved the problem. In my case the conflicting files were `WAStorageEmulatorDb34.*`, but will probably be some higher number in future versions.

Comment: Removing the `AzureStorageEmulatorDb41*` files in C:\Users\{myuser} fixed an install failure I was getting on fresh Windows 10 install of Storage Emulator 4.1 also.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue with v2.95 of the SDK from the web platform installer. I am on Windows 10 with SQL 2016 express installed. Here's how I fixed it on my dev machine:

In an elevated cmd prompt run to get a list of all localdb instances:
`sqllocaldb.exe info`

Then for every instance shown above, run the following to delete them:
`sqllocaldb.exe delete 'instanceName'`

Now kill all sqlserver.exe processes (`Get-Process sqlservr` | `Stop-Process`)

Delete everything under this location:
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances`

I also had multiple orphaned instances listed here in the registry (Thanks procmon). Delete all of the ones that do not have any data configured under the instance GUIDs. You should see a datadirectory, instance name, and other information about each one. If you don't, then delete it.
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances`

Finally, create a new instance of localdb:
`sqllocaldb.exe create`

The SDK finally installed!

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the solution was to delete `%UserProfile%\AzureStorageEmulatorDb*` files, then re-running the installation

Answer (score 0):

I notice a mixture of drive letters in your dump (C:\, G:\, O;).  Be aware that code 1603 can come from trying to install from certain locations like a shared or network drive.  I would recommend trying to work backwards - maybe try and re-install WebPI from a known location on a local drive and ensure that it won't try to dump contents elsewhere.  Are you running this as a user that has raised (admin) privileges?